# When does Son Goku learn to fly?

Tags: dragon-ball-series

In chapter 202 of the DragonBall manga, Goku floats into the air to see where his child is:

[image: floating]

Then when he is travelling along the green scale road, he flies a portion of the way there. He also flies to assist combatting the Saiyans after his training with the Lord of the Worlds.

When did Goku learn how to fly, when previously he had only used Kintou for aerial movement?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The first time we see Goku fly is in Chapter 193, page 10. Krillin, Master Roshi and Tien actually describe it as the Air Dance. Since the first time he saw the Air Dance was at the previous tournament, we can conclude that he learnt in in between the 2nd and 3rd tournament, during his time training with Kami. 
[image]

Answer (score 11):

It was never shown, how he learned to fly, so that's pure speculation. The DragonBall-Wiki has a possible explanation:

> Goku likely learned how to fly from Kami during his long training at Kami's Lookout, as he was unable to do so before and demonstrated his abilities to conclude his World Martial Arts Tournament fight with Piccolo.

Source: [Dragonball Wiki](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Flight)

Comment: Ah that makes sense, seeing as Piccolo can fly using his special technique, and Kami was also a Namekian

Comment: I could be mistaken, as I'm not referencing any sources now, but didn't Krillin, Yamcha, and Goku learn the Air Dance that Tien and Chaotzu already knew during a time skip after defeating king Piccolo but before the World Martial Arts Tournament where Goku and Piccolo fight?

Comment: @Nil Krillin indeed, because he flies when fighting against Piccolo. But I don't think Yamcha could fly at that moment.

Answer (score 5):

Goku learned to fly during the first tournament arc while he was fighting Jackie Chun.

Albeit, he flew by rotating his tail like a helicopter, which is a different technique than normal.

[image]

Comment: +1 nice find! What about when he used his Kamehameha to fly? Not sure if thats counts too ;)

Answer (score -2):

I think Goku learned to fly at Kaio's planet (at least I think so in the anime). When they fought Raditz, he still used the Kintoun Cloud. And he died that fight.

Comment: He seems to pretty clearly be flying without the cloud in the manga panels from the OP, which is during the Raditz fight.

Comment: It could just be DBZTime floating.

Comment: I believe that Goku flew fighting Piccolo Jr. towards the end of Dragon Ball. I believe he already knew the Air Dance but flew slower than his kintoun/flying nimbus. That's probably why he used that to get to Raditz, but I don't have a source to verify it.

Comment: @Nil i'm pretty sure you got it right.  Numbus, was FAST.  easily keeping up with Piccolo's flight, and at the time, Goku hadn't gotten a death-powerup yet, so his ability to output enough energy for flight was most likely not as high as it could have been.