# What was the original idea for the origin of Goku (if there was)?

Tags: dragon-ball

I believe that Toriyama didn't have on start in its mind the idea of Goku's origin being that of a saiyajin alien or even something similar, it doesn't match at all with the concepts shown in the first Dragon ball series.

I know it's based on Sun Wukong from Journey to the West, but I think it's just an inspiration for the character, not that the character origin was going to be the same than that character.

Has Toriyama ever stated what was his original idea for the origin of Goku? If so, which was it? Or didn't he think about that until the Raditz Saga?

Comment: related: [Is Goku in Dragonball based on Sun Wukong from Journey to the West?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/32156/2869)

Comment: I don't have anything concrete, but Toriyama is no stranger to writing by the seat of his pants.  He makes things up, forgets other parts of cannon, etc.  My guess would be it was never intended.  I believe the show was supposed to be a kind of one season thing where the first wish on the dragon and the defeat of Emperor Pilaf was supposed to be the end of it.  Then it got very popular and continued long past it's original intended story.  Thus triclopses, demons-that-are-later-aliens, alien monkeys, alien emperors, bug-men, cyborgs, pink universe ending demons and cat gods.

Comment: I agree with @Becuzz. One way or another DB was just intended to be one series/season at best. It was inspired by Journey to the West but has its own story. It just got popular enough to be extended and expanded the Saiyan Race lore.